# При отсутствии палиндрома должно выводиться '0'

Tags: python

```
word = str(input())
n = 0

while word.replace(word[n], '') != word.replace(word[n], '')[::-1]:
    if word.replace(word[n], '') == word.replace(word[n], '')[::-1]:
        break
    elif n > len(word):
        n = 0
    else:
        n += 1

if n > 0:
    print(n+1)
else:
    print(n)
```

Задача такая: на вход получается слово, если при удалении какой-либо буквы появляется палиндром, то пишется номер буквы, а если палиндром невозможен, то пишется 0. У меня получилось сделать первую часть, но вторая никак не удается.

Пример работы:

```
| Ввод      | Вывод          |
| --------- | -------------- |
| raceczar  | 6              |
| car       | 0              |
```

Comment: `str(input())` в этом, кстати, нет смысла, можно просто `input()` — оттуда и так всегда прилетает строка.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
word = str(input())
n = 0

while True:
    if word[:n] + word[n + 1:] == (word[:n] + word[n + 1:])[::-1]:
        break
    elif n == len(word) - 1:
        print(0)
        exit(0)
    else:
        n += 1

print(n+1)
```

Comment: Можно `print(n+1)` перенести к `break`, тогда вместо `exit` можно тоже `break` поставить. А то `exit` это как-то слишком мне кажется )

Comment: Можно. Но мне было лень.

Comment: Уважительная причина!